# How to filter the legend according to the current Atlas page?

Tags: qgis, cartography, print-composer

I filter the legend by map in the map composer. Some symbols must be used for two legend entries, as you can see below.

[image]

When I start the atlas tool, the legend displays - if the symbol contained by the map - both legend entries. Is it possible to filter the legend by the atlas and not by the map.